# Is it possible to find the 0th index-position of a 2D numpy array (not) containing a given vaule?

Tags: python, numpy, search

## Is it possible to find the 0th index-position of a 2D numpy array (not) containing a given vaule?

### What I want, and expect

I have a 2D numpy array containing integers. My goal is to find the index of the array(s) that do not contain a given value (using numpy functions). Here is an example of such an array, named `ortho_disc`:

```
>>> ortho_disc 
Out: [[1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
      [1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0]
      [0 0 0 0 0 0 2 2 0]]
```

If I wish to find the arrays not containing 2, I would expect an output of `[0, 1]`, as the first and second array of `ortho_disc` does not contain the value 2.

### What I have tried

I have looked into `np.argwhere`, `np.nonzero`, `np.isin` and `np.where` without expected results. My best attempt using `np.where` was the following:

```
>>> np.where(2 not in ortho_disc, [True]*3, [False]*3) 
Out: [False False False]
```

But it does not return the expected `[True, True, False]`. This is especially weird after we look at the output `ortho_disc`'s arrays evaluated by themselves:

```
>>> 2 not in ortho_disc[0] 
Out: True

>>> 2 not in ortho_disc[1] 
Out:True

>>> 2 not in ortho_disc[2]
Out: False
```

#### Using argwhere

Using `np.argwhere`, all I get is an empty array (not the expected `[0, 1]`):

```
>>> np.argwhere(2 not in ortho_disc) 
Out: []
```

I suspect this is because numpy first flattens `ortho_disc`, then checks the truth-value of `2 not in ortho_disc`?
The same empty array is returned using `np.nonzero(2 not in ortho_disc)`.

### My code

```
import numpy as np
ortho_disc = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                       [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0,]])
polymer = 2

print(f'>>> ortho_disc \nOut:\n{ortho_disc}\n')
print(f'>>> {polymer} not in {ortho_disc[0]} \nOut: {polymer not in ortho_disc[0]}\n')
print(f'>>> {polymer} not in {ortho_disc[1]} \nOut: {polymer not in ortho_disc[1]}\n')
print(f'>>> {polymer} not in {ortho_disc[2]} \nOut: {polymer not in ortho_disc[2]}\n\n')

breakpoint = np.argwhere(polymer not in ortho_disc)
print(f'>>>np.argwhere({polymer} not in ortho_disc) \nOut: {breakpoint}\n\n\n')
```

Output:

```
>>> ortho_disc 
Out:
[[1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 2 2 0]]

>>> 2 not in [1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0] 
Out: True

>>> 2 not in [1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0] 
Out: True

>>> 2 not in [0 0 0 0 0 0 2 2 0] 
Out: False


>>>np.argwhere(2 not in ortho_disc) 
Out: []
```

#### Expected output

From the bottom two lines:

```
breakpoint = np.argwhere(polymer not in ortho_disc)
print(f'>>>np.argwhere({polymer} not in ortho_disc) \nOut: {breakpoint}\n\n\n')
```

I excpect the following output:

```
>>>np.argwhere(2 not in ortho_disc) 
Out: [0, 1]
```

### Summary

I would really love feedback on how to solve this issue, as I have been scratching my head over what seems to be an easy problem for ages. And as I mentioned it is important to avoid the obvious 'easy-way-out' loop over `ortho_disc`, preferably using numpy.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Will you please also add a sample of your expected output to the question?

Comment: @richardec sorry! I should have been more clear on the expected output. As I added in the post: I am expect the array of indices: `[0, 1]`. 
@WarrenWeckesser's solution worked perfectly, although I don't understand all the intricacies just yet.

Comment: Yeah, a nice header would've been good, but I didn't read closely. Take a look at my ans :)

Comment: @richardec Thank you so much! I totally understand the progression now:D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [13]: ortho_disc
Out[13]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0]])

In [14]: polymer = 2

In [15]: (ortho_disc != polymer).all(axis=1).nonzero()[0]
Out[15]: array([0, 1])
```

Breaking it down: `ortho_disc != polymer` is an array of bools:

```
In [16]: ortho_disc != polymer
Out[16]: 
array([[ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False, False,  True]])
```

We want the rows that are all True; for that, we can apply the `all()` method along axis 1 (i.e. along the rows):

```
In [17]: (ortho_disc != polymer).all(axis=1)
Out[17]: array([ True,  True, False])
```

That's the boolean mask for the rows that do not contain `polymer`.

Use `nonzero()` to find the indices of the values that are not 0 (True is considered nonzero, False is 0):

```
In [19]: (ortho_disc != polymer).all(axis=1).nonzero()
Out[19]: (array([0, 1]),)
```

Note that `nonzero()` returned a tuple with length 1; in general, it returns a tuple with the same length as the number of dimensions of the array.  Here the input array is 1-d.  Pull out the desired result from the tuple by indexing with `[0]`:

```
In [20]: (ortho_disc != polymer).all(axis=1).nonzero()[0]
Out[20]: array([0, 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy broadcasting for this. `ortho_disc == 2` will return a mask of the array where each value is True if that value in the array was not `2`, False if it was `2`. Then, use `np.all` with `axis=1` to condense each row into a boolean indicating whether or not that row contained only True values (True value = no `2` there):

```
>>> np.all(ortho_disc != 2, axis=1)
array([ True,  True, False])
```

If you want to get the indexes out that, just `np.where` with the above:

```
>>> np.where(np.all(ortho_disc != 2, axis=1))[0]
array([0, 1])
```